# How to UV Correctly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

I cannot find any useful tutorials somehow. My model has awful UVs and I want to know how to fix them. What is the workflow to fix this type of thing or a useful tutorial for it. I do not know[image] much about UV unwrapping but I have marked seams and done a smart project. The normal UV project was terrible. The smart one was okay but had so many UV seams it was impossible to use.

[image]

These are for one of the answer discussions:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I get a picture of your UVW map and a better angle/view of the seams please? If you were really struggling I could make a short video on how you'd unwrap this particular model.

Comment: Please post images of your model in the 3D viewport and in the UV Editor so that we can see if your mesh is subdivided and unwrapped correctly.

Comment: I added the photo. This was with smart UV project. The other was with unwrap.

Comment: Have you tried using "Follow Active Quads" as demonstrated in this video? It seems that Blender is deforming your cylindrical shapes and that's what is causing distortion. This will straighten those cylindrical shapes out for you and should fix the problem. Also you've got four seams for that handle when you only need the one. Unwrap it with a single seam and then apply the below method.

SIDE NOTE: In the video he says to search for "Follow Active Quads" but you can also find it by pressing 'U' in the 3D viewport and finding it there. Hope this helps! https://youtu.be/bHbgQs8zkpw

Comment: So it undoubtedly worked for the handle and it looks great. I am just not sure what I would do with the rest of the parts since their UVs don't seem to be that way and more spherical. I have added two more photos to show this.

Comment: Those other parts may still unwrap as cylinder if you make a cut around it at the top of that lip, just where it connects to the base of that plain cylinder (the main one with the explosive in it) then make another cut down the side and try a normal unwrap. If you get distortion then trying cutting down the edge going through that circular inset. Using the same method to unwrap it doesn't work every time so it's best to try different methods. Smart project is good for some things but not everything. If you really get stuck I could look at the model for you?

Comment: I should be fine. Thank you so much! I will definitely use this in the future!

Comment: Please ask the OP any questions you might have in the comment section instead of the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

right click and click unwrap.
If you want it to look even better, click on uv>smart uv project.
This will take longer, but gives considerably better results than just simply unwrapping.

Comment: My issue (said in the description) is that the smart UV has seams that mess up the UV in texturing and the normal unwrap just goes crazy.